# KIVYMD ThreeLineAvatarListItem

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

i use ThreeLineAvatarListItem in kivymd and i'm wondering how you can use an image from an url,

when i use a local image it's working but when it's an url, i receive this message:

> [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found
> https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/art_crop/front/0/1/01cb2a12-4c1c-413d-91b1-574e4a00e251.jpg?1581630415

the code i use is this one :

```
for row in result:
    image = ImageLeftWidget(source=row[3])
    items = ThreeLineAvatarListItem(text=row[0], secondary_text=row[1],tertiary_text=row[2])
    items.add_widget(image)
    lv.add_widget(items)
```

row[3] contains "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/art_crop/front/0/1/01cb2a12-4c1c-413d-91b1-574e4a00e251.jpg?1581630415"

is there a way to do that ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your own version of `ImageLeftWidget` that uses `AsyncImage` instead of `Image`, like this:

```
class AsyncImageLeftWidget(ILeftBody, AsyncImage):
    pass
```

Then use this class in your code in place of `ImageLeftWidget`.